# SQL Server : update the same table after insert

Tags: sql-server

I'm a beginner in SQL. I use Microsoft SQL Server and database for delivering bulk data from another system (different software on other pc).

I would like to update one column for just inserted rows. I created a trigger to update inserted rows, but this trigger do not update anything. It can update any other table, but update of the same table for rows have been just inserted do not work.

If I insert data directly in SSMS then it works - the same table where rows are inserted, are updated after insert. But data inserted from other system/server are not updated. Actually data are not even inserted. Have no idea why.

I was looking for any solution, found that MySQL cant update the same table what is being used for reading/writing. I don't know if the same logic is valid for SQL Server - but why manual insert works then?

This is my trigger:

```
  ALTER trigger [cw].[mytrigger]
  ON [cw].[TABLE1]
  AFTER INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @FBN nvarchar(10)

      DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
          SELECT FEEDBNO FROM inserted

      OPEN db_cursor  

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @FBN

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
      BEGIN
          UPDATE cw.TABLE1
          SET WCGroup = CASE
                           WHEN WCGroup = 'GROUP1' THEN 'GROUP_11'
                           WHEN WCGroup = 'GROUP2' THEN 'GROUP_22.'
          WHERE FeedbackNo = @FBN           

          FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @FBN
      END

      CLOSE db_cursor
      DEALLOCATE db_cursor
  END
```

I appreciate any help or solution. Thanks.

UPDATE:
OK, solved another way. Problem was most likely ETL job runnig on source system. I created a new column in destination table and trigger insert required value into this column based on inserted data. Updating column used in ETL by trigger didn't work properly. 
Thanks for anwers, I learned something new.

Comment: You don't need a cursor. You can perform the update as a set-based operation by joining `inserted` on the table's primary key. I would post sample code but you didn't include the `CREATE TABLE` DDL in your question.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you understand the way the commit transactions work for the stuff coming from other systems? That sounds to me as if it could be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few flaws with your trigger. Firstly, the cursor is a bad idea, so we should get rid of that; treat your data as it is; a dataset. Next, your `CASE` is missing an `END`, so you should be getting a syntax error. i believe this fixes the problem (You'll need to correct `YourIDColumn` to the appropriate column name):

```
ALTER TRIGGER cw.mytrigger ON cw.Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN

  UPDATE T1
  SET WCGroup = CASE i.WCGroup WHEN 'GROUP1' THEN 'GROUP_11'
                               WHEN 'GROUP2' THEN 'GROUP_22.'
                               ELSE i.WCGroup END
  FROM cw.table1 T1
       JOIN inserted i ON T1.YourIDColumn = i.YourIDColumn;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I modified trigger accordding code above, unfortunately problem persists. If trigger is enabled neither insert nor update is performed for incomming data. Manual insert in Management studio works.
As for incomming data, they are inserted using ETL function of the source system.

Comment: Considering that trigger only effects `INSERT` statements, @ThePegass it's your ETL that is the problem. That trigger wouldnt stop an `UPDATE` from working.